# General Python syntax error with triple quotes

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a Python script that lists every file in an image directory to an html file. In the script below I'm getting an "invalid syntax" error and it points to line 33 but I don't know what is causing it specifically.

Here is the code:

```
import zipfile
import paginate
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


# def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
#     with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
#         zf.extractall(dest_dir)

# unzip('test.zip', '')

onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir('images') if isfile(join('images',f)) ]

page = 1
my_page = paginate.Page(onlyfiles, page)

html_app = ""
print my_page.items

for filename in enumerate(my_page.items):
    html_str = """
    <center>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
            function pic"""+str(filename[0])+"""()
            {
                document.getElementById("img").src = "images/"""+filename[1]"""";
            }
        </script>

        <img src = "" id = "img"/> <input type="button" value="File: " onclick="pic"""+str(filename[0])+"""()"/>


        <br><br>
    </center>

    """
#   <a href="./images/"""+filename[1]+""" ">"""+filename[1]+"""</a><br>

html_app+=html_str

Html_file= open("filename.html","a")
Html_file.write(html_str)
Html_file.close()
print "Done."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a + after `+filename[1]` to concat the strings:

```
 "images/"""+filename[1]""" # <- missing a +
```

Should be `document.getElementById("img").src = "images/"""+filename[1]+""";"`

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! Thank you!